# What is the HTMLObjectElement: willValidate property and its application?

Tags: javascript, validation

It seems that `willValidate` always returns `true`.

When you put both in an input-event-listener of an `<input>` you will always receive `true` from `willValidate` but `checkValidity()` will return `false` when input is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `false` if the element is [barred from constraint validation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#barred-from-constraint-validation), i.e for when the browser will not run its `checkValidity()` if posted to a form.

A few cases where this happens:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-comment]").forEach((el) => {
  console.log(el.willValidate, el.dataset.comment);
});
```

```html
<input data-comment="true">
<input type=hidden data-comment="type=hidden">
<input type=button data-comment="type=button">
<button type=button data-comment="&lt;button type=button>"></button>
<input readonly data-comment="readonly">
<datalist>
  <input data-comment="descendant of a &lt;datalist>">
</datalist>
```

You can click on the bold text in the specs to see a few more cases where this would be set.